# Can't seem to run a process in background of Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to display a number from an api, but I want my page to load faster. So, I'd like to get the number from the api every 5 minutes, and just load that number to my page. This is what I have.

```
get '/' do
  x = Numbersapi.new
  @number = x.number
  :erb home
end
```

This works fine, but getting that number from the api takes a while so that means my page takes a while to load. I want to look up that number ahead of time and then every 5 minutes. I've tried using threads and processes, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm still pretty new to programming.

Comment: Look into using sidekiq and redis. Sidekiq job will run in the background, fetch that expensive data and store in redis, from which the value will be read by your sinatra app.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty simple way to get data in a separate thread. Somewhere outside of the controller action, fire off the async loop:

```
Data = {}
numbers_api = Numbersapi.new
Thread.new do
  Data[:number] = numbers_api.number
  sleep 300 # 5 minutes
end
```

Then in your controller action, you can simply refer to the `Data[:number]`, and you'll get the latest value.

However if you're deploying this you should use a gem like Resque or Sidekiq; it will track failures and is probably optimized more